# How to convert columns to rows Datewise in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a data in the following format

| Date | AA_ZZ_CR | AA_ZZ_BT | AA_XX_CR | AA_XX_BT | BB_ZZ_CR | BB_ZZ_BT | BB_XX_CR | BB_XX_BT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230202 | 20 | 56 | 34 | 556 | 29 | 59 | 32 | 559 |
| 20230203 | 21 | 45 | 54 | 423 | 28 | 48 | 53 | 426 |
| 20230204 | 22 | 78 | 23 | 790 | 27 | 76 | 29 | 794 |
| 20230205 | 23 | 78 | 56 | 778 | 26 | 72 | 51 | 771 |
| 20230206 | 24 | 89 | 78 | 855 | 25 | 81 | 79 | 850 |
| 20230207 | 25 | 56 | 89 | 545 | 24 | 54 | 86 | 543 |

Want it converted into Date format.

| Date | Data | ZZ_CR | ZZ_BT | XX_CR | XX_BT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230202 | AA | 20 | 56 | 34 | 556 |
| 20230202 | BB | 29 | 59 | 32 | 559 |
| 20230203 | AA | 21 | 45 | 54 | 423 |
| 20230203 | BB | 28 | 48 | 53 | 426 |

Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: Maybe clarify first: Is this a Pandas dataframe, a PySpark dataframe, or which library are you using?

Comment: Pandas dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get you desire output within one line if you have one similar category but here we have multiple so I have used loop, to just need to merge new column with Date.

**With Pandas:**

```
##Get the list of columns except unnecessary ones like date
columns = df.columns[1:]

#Get the set new columns headers like from AA_ZZ_BT split and get ZZ_BT 
uni = set([i.split('_',1)[1] for i in df.columns[1:]])

#Now we know how many new column will need to loop over that set
for idx, u in enumerate(uni):
    
    #Step 1 find the similar columns
    find_col = columns[[u in i for i in columns]]

    #Step 2 create new df with and include date columns as well
    d = df[['Date'] + list(find_col)]

    #step 3 using melt function pivot the table
    d = d.melt(id_vars=['Date'], value_vars=find_col, var_name='Data', value_name=u)

    #Now still we have to clean Data column by splitting AA from AA_ZZ_BT
    d['Data'] = d['Data'].str.slice(stop=2)
    
    #Final step if its first time then take whole d as new_df else concat the last col with new_df
    new_df=d if idx==0 else pd.concat([new_df, d[u]], axis=1)

        
new_df  #output
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem consists mostly of manipulating and renaming some columns if you take the looping through columns approach. I am assuming your data is in a dataframe called `df`.

```py
data_entries = list(set(col[:2] for col in df.columns[1:]))
data_entries.sort()

dfs_split = []
for entry in data_entries: 
    # Get the Date and Data columns 
    cols = ['Date'] + [col for col in df.columns if entry in col]    
    df_data = df[cols]
    # Add the Data column 
    df_data.insert(1, 'Data', entry)
    # Take out the Data prefix on the columns
    df_data = df_data.rename(lambda x: x.replace(f'{entry}_', ''), axis=1)
    dfs_split.append(df_data)
        
df = pd.concat(dfs_split, axis=0)    
df = df.sort_values(by='Date')
df
```